# How to feed a model with "a list of outputs"?

Tags: keras

Sorry for the title but I could't come up with a better description here.

I am trying to apply batches for training on a model which should have 13 fully connected output layers. Each output layer has only two nodes (but are fully connected as stated).

Building the model's output looks like this:

```py
outputs = list()

for i in range(num_labels):
    out_y = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='out_{:d}'.format(i))(convolution_layer)
    outputs.append(out_y)

self.model = Model(input=inputs, output=outputs)
```

However, I can't manage to feed this model. I've tried to go with a `[batch_size, 13, 1, 2]` sized output array:

```py
y = np.zeros((batch_size, 13, 1, 2))
```

But for a batch of size 2 I get:

```
ValueError: The model expects 13 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (2, 13, 1, 2)
```

I've tried several other things but it's simply not clear to me how the input for the model looks like.

How can I train this model?

---

I have also tried to pass a list of lists of numpy arrays:

[image]

where the first level of the batch represent the sample (here 2) and the second level is the sample with the list of 13 numpy arrays. Yet I am getting:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: you are passing a list as input to your model, but the model expects a list of 13 Numpy arrays instead. The list you passed was: [[array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  0.]), array([
```

---

As suggested, I also tried to return a `list()` of numpy arrays of size `[13,2]`:

[image]

Where the error becomes:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 13 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ ...
```

---

#### The code

Below you can find the current code which generates one sample in `sample_generator` and a full batch in `batch_generator` (which uses `sample_generator`).

def batch_generator(w2v, file_path, meta_info, batch_size, sample_generator_fn, embedding_size):

**Please note:** The code shows now how I generate a `list()` of `[13,2]` ndarrays whereas the number of such ndarrays in that list is defined by `batch_size`.

```py
    try:

    x = np.zeros((batch_size, meta_info.max_sequence_length, embedding_size, 1))
    y = list() #np.zeros((batch_size, 13, 1, 2))

    file = open(file_path)

    while True:

        x[:] = 0.0
        #y[:] = 0.0

        for batch in range(batch_size):

            sentence_info_json = file.readline()

            if sentence_info_json == '':
                file.seek(0)
                sentence_info_json = file.readline()

            sample = sample_generator_fn(w2v, sentence_info_json, meta_info)

            if not sample:
                continue

            sentence_embedding = sample[0]

            final_length = len(sentence_embedding)

            x[batch, :final_length, :, 0] = sentence_embedding
            y.append(sample[1])

        shuffled = np.asarray(range(batch_size))
        np.random.shuffle(shuffled)

        x = x[shuffled]
        #y = y[shuffled]
        y = [y[i] for i in shuffled]

        yield x, y

    except Exception as e:
    print('Error in generator.')
    print(e)
    raise e


def sample_generator(w2v, sentence_info_json, meta_info):

    if not sentence_info_json:
    print('???')

    sentence_info = json.loads(sentence_info_json)

    tokens = [token['word'] for token in sentence_info['corenlp']['tokens']]
    sentence = Sentence(tokens=tokens)

    sentence_embedding = w2v.get_word_vectors(sentence.tokens.tolist())
    sentence_embedding = np.asarray([word_vector for word_vector in sentence_embedding if word_vector is not None])

    final_length = len(sentence_embedding)

    if final_length == 0:
    return None

    y = np.zeros((2, len(meta_info.category_dict)))
    y[1, :] = 1.

    #y_list = []

    y_tar = np.zeros((len(meta_info.category_dict), 2))

    for i in range(len(meta_info.category_dict)):
    y_tar[i][1] = 1.0
    # y_list.append(np.asarray([0.0, 1.0]))

    for opinion in sentence_info['opinions']:
    index = meta_info.category_dict[opinion['category']]

    y_tar[index][0] = 1.0
    y_tar[index][1] = 0.0

    #y_list[index][0] = 1.0
    #y_list[index][1] = 0.0

    return sentence_embedding, y_tar
```

As requested, the call to `fit_generator()`

```py
cnn.model.fit_generator(generator=batch_generator(word2vec,
                                                  train_file, train_meta_info,
                                                  num_batches, sample_generator,
                                                  embedding_size),
                        samples_per_epoch=2000,
                        nb_epoch=2,
                        # validation_data=batch_generator(test_file_path, train_meta_info),
                        # nb_val_samples=100,
                        verbose=True)
```

Comment: To which method have you fed this array? Fit or predict?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I am using `fit_generator()`

Comment: Could you provide us a full code with this methods calls.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Which one? I am not sure if the call to `fit_generator()` would help here. I can however post the sample generator (see update)

Comment: But could you show us the code with a call of model.fit_generator()?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I am very certain that this won't help but I added it to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output should be a list as specified in the error. Each element of the list should be a numpy array of size `[batch_size, nb_outputs]`. So a list of 13 elements of size `[batch_size,2]` in your case.

Comment: This cannot work because I have to provide at least a 13x2 matrix as input *for each* sample. that means I cannot go below `[batch_size, 13, 2]` or something similar.

Comment: A list of 13 arrays of size `[batch_size,2]` is `13 * batch_size * 2` which is exactly the same number of elements as `[batch_size, 13, 2]`

Comment: But you're saying "*Each element of the list should be a numpy array of size `[batch_size, nb_outputs]`*". What you mean then is "*each element should be a `[13, 2]` numpy array*", right? because I am very sure that I tried that.

Comment: I updated my question. The last example is a `list()` of `[13, 2]` ndarrays where the list has `batch_size` of such ndarrays.

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. A `list()` of length 13, with each element of the list of size `[batch_size,2]`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: This really did the trick. This is very ugly imho. I don't understand why it's not possible to pass a `[batch_size, 13, 2]` ndarray. I really hope they change that if at all possible.

Comment: Well keep in mind that often each element has a different size, so the `list()` format is necessary. So you can have a list that is e.g. `[[batch_size,2],[batch_size,4]]`. But you cant do that with a simple numpy array.

Comment: You're right - this makes sense of course. I didn't think about that.