# Why do I get the same prediction for all training samples?

Tags: keras

I have a neural network with `num_labels` separate outputs where each output consists of a *softmax* layer with two nodes (Yes/No).

I am taking the output of a `convolution_layer` and feed it as input for a simple `softmax_layer` which I further feed into each of said outputs:

```py
softmax_layer = Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax', name='softmax_layer')(convolution_layer)

outputs = list()

for i in range(num_labels):
    out_y = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='out_{:d}'.format(i))(softmax_layer)
    outputs.append(out_y)
```

So far I was able to train the model by [providing a list of training samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259071/how-to-feed-a-model-with-a-list-of-outputs) but now I noticed that I am getting the exact same output for completely different samples in a batch:

> **Please note:** Here, each column consists of (2,1) arrays. *Each* column is the prediction for *one* sample.

[image]

I've checked the samples, they **are** different. I've also tried to e.g. feed the `convolution_layer` into the outputs. In that case the predictions are different. I can only see this outcome if I do it the way shown above.

I could live with the fact that the outputs are "similar". In that case I'd think that the network is just learning not what I want it to learn but since they are really the *same* I am not quite sure what the problem here is.

---

I've tried something similar with a simple feed forward network:

```py
class FeedForward:

    def __init__(self, input_dim, nb_classes):

        in_x = Input(shape=(input_dim, ), name='in_x')
        h1 = Dense(14, name='h1', activation='relu')(in_x)
        h2 = Dense(8, name='h2', activation='relu')(h1)
        out = Dense(nb_classes, name='out', activation='softmax')(h2)

        self.model = Model(input=[in_x], output=[out])

    def compile_model(self, optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy'):
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

But it behaves similarly. I can't imagine it's due to imbalanced data. There are 13 classes. There is some imbalance but it's not like that one class has 90% of the mass.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Are your yes/no classes balanced? Is one much more common than the other?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro No, they are not balanced and you're right, this would cause an issue here and the result might not be very satisfying here. However, it's still strange that the results are completely equal for all samples, isn't it?

Comment: Depends how much imbalance there is, problem is that if one of the classes is 90% of the data, then a NN can learn to always output that class and get rewarded by 90% accuracy.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro fyi I am asking this in the github repository with code for a running example + the required data set (csv file). Take a look if you want: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5992